# stop function execution before ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Help me please!
I have a table with a clear button on each row. when I click the clear button I need to open a bootstrap modal, depending on OK or cancel button clicks on modal my function should delete the row or not.

upon clear button click I have a function (Removefile) that deletes that particular row.
I am trying to open the modal first and depending on Modal button clicks OK or Cancel I want rest of the ajax call to be executed or stopped.

```
function Removefile(strfileid) {
       $('#myModal').modal({'show' : true});
            $('#btnCancel').click(function(event) {
              e.preventDefault(); //does not stop ajax call
               return false; //does not stop ajax call
                }

           });
         $.ajax({
            url: 'xxxx.aspx/RemoveFile',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            data: '{"strMissingFileID":"' + strfileid+ '"}',
            success: function (r) {

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                alert(jqXHR.statusText);
            }
        });

    }
```

when btnCancel from the modal is clicked I do not want any further execution of code. it should exit but it still executes and row gets deleted. Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is adding an event handler, then calling ajax. You are returning false from that handler when the button is clicked, so it won't stop anything from running in the `Removefile` function.

Comment: Don't try to "cancel" the AJAX call, simply do the AJAX call instead on the OK button.  Ignore the cancel button.

Comment: Thanks for responding HereticMonkey. what would be the right way to stop Removefile function then. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for responding Patrick. Will try your approach.